# .Net Skipping Code

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, public-key-encryption

I am having a strange problem. I am working on a .net windows project using c# code behind. I am trying to encrypt/decrypt files using public/private keys. This has happened to me a few times since I start working on encryption. The actual issue of how to get encryption to work will be another posting later.

The problem is that while stepping through my code the pointer exits the routine. It does not crash or get caught in the try/catch block.

In the case below the line to get the public key works, but the line to get the private key does not. it just skips out and returns to the calling module.

```
string publicKey; // gets the public key
string privateKey; // gets the private key
try
{
    CspParameters cspParam = new CspParameters();
    cspParam.Flags = CspProviderFlags.UseMachineKeyStore;
    System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider RSA =
        new System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider(cspParam);
    //        The key information
    //from the cspParam object above can be saved via
    //select the;
    publicKey = RSA.ToXmlString(false); // gets the public key
    privateKey = RSA.ToXmlString(true); // gets the private key
    string x = publicKey;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    clsGetMessage.DisplayError(ex);
}
```

Comment: Hard to say, but I'd suspect it's an issue with permissions (ASP.NET process not having rights to private keys), perhaps throwing an exception that doesn't derive from Exception.

Comment: Do you mean Windows Forms or ASP.NET? Windows forms doesn't have codebehind.

Comment: It is windows forms in Visual Studio.

Comment: Regarding Tiago comment. I went to my profile but I didn't see what you were talking about. Please be more specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you say this based on the debugging using VS? 
did you verify the stack trace or logs to see if the method is called?

VS debuggers may guide you wrong in multi threaded cases.

Comment: I can see that the lines were not executed by looking at the variables in the immediate window.

Comment: I never did figure out why the code was being skipped. But I found an excellent example, written in C# that accomplished what I wanted. That is getting RSA Encryption working with C# code. I was able to get it to work fairly easily.

http://www.dotnetspider.com/attachments/Resources/692-RSA-Encryption-C.aspx

Thanks to Anita Joseph.

Bob

Answer (score 0):

Since PrivateKey is not used anywhere, maybe function call is cut away by compiler?